# Compilation appears not showing compilation errors (Makefile)

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I've created a makefile for a project, but I think it's only showing linking error and not the compilation errors themselves. Can anyone review my Makefile and spot any mistake I may have made?

```
# =========== vars =========== 

objects = directories user server 
CC = gcc
OUT_DIR = bin
USER_EXEC = ${OUT_DIR}/user
SERVER_EXEC = ${OUT_DIR}/server

CFLAGS = -g -D_REENTRANT -pthread -Wall 

SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
USER_SRC = $(wildcard ./src/user/*.c) $(SRC)
SERVER_SRC = $(wildcard ./src/server/*.c) $(SRC)

USER_OBJ = $(USER_SRC:.c=.o)
SERVER_OBJ = $(SERVER_SRC:.c=.o)

# =========== targets =========== 

all: $(objects)

directories: 
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)

user: $(USER_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(USER_OBJ) -o $(USER_EXEC)

server: $(SERVER_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SERVER_SRC) -o $(SERVER_EXEC)

clean:
    rm -f $(USER_EXEC) $(SERVER_EXEC) src/*.o src/user/*.o src/server/*.o
```

Comment: Possible you have a `.o` lying around that's newer than the `.c`? Typical mistake when developing Makefiles.

Comment: Whenever you modify a `Makefile` you should `make clean`

Comment: The recipes for your `user` and `server` rules do not in fact build those rules' targets.  That's probably not the cause of your error, but you should still fix it.  They also have an unspecified, disguised dependency on `$(OUT_DIR)`, which could be a genuine problem if you try to build one of those targets directly, instead of via the default target or `all`.

Comment: 1. You don't have a rule that turns .c to .o; `make` will use its own implicit rule in this case. 2. `clean` should better explicitly refer to `$(USER_OBJ)` etc. 3. Better use other name than `objects`; in `make` context it's rather "object files" than your programs. 4. Add dependency: `$(objects): directories`, but better refer to directory itself and not a target. 5. Use .PHONY. 6. Use separate directory for object files.